# Multiple list views - auto height for all of them

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I'm trying to resolve some layout problems in my Xamarin.Forms application. For example, when height of content is higher than body content height, then lists will collapse.

I have undefined amount of lists with custom item templates. I want to remain all height of each list and have possibility of scrolling them.

I tried use StackLayout but it doesn't support scrolling. When I use ScrollView, the Auto property doesn't work correctly (there is ambigous space between each of lists).

My code looks like this:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
...
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid Grid.Row="0"> //Header
...
</Grid>

<StackLayout Grid.Row="1"> //Group of lists

<ListView x:Name="firstList" ItemTemplate="..." ItemsSource="...">
</ListView>
<ListView x:Name="secondList" ItemTemplate="..." ItemsSource="...">
</ListView>
...

</StackLayout>

</Grid>
```

How can I position these lists on full height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to achieve is very ambiguous from the mobile app perspective. Think the other way around: While your screen is full of stacked `ListView`s, how would the system know it has to scroll down the page or scroll down the current `ListView`?

Also nesting ListView into ScrollView is a very bad practice because:

1. `ListView` implements its own scrolling.
2. `ListView` will not receive any gestures -> they will be handled by the parent ScrollView.
3. also `ListView` can have customized header and footer that scrolls with the elements of the list, potentially offering the functionality that the ScrollView was used for.

If you want to stick to this layout, your option here would be to design your own implementation of your control using custom renderers and manage the gesture.

Hope it helps and happy coding!